# Add event handler on click with specific selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm trying to add an event handler on the document on the `li` selector. In JQuery, this will work:

```
$('li').click(function(){
   var justify = $(this).attr('data-cid');
   alert(justify);
});
```

how can I do the **exact** same thing in JavaScript?

Comment: @HarishKommuri what are you referring to?

Comment: Technically it is JavaScript...

Comment: @epascarello it's JQuery.

Comment: Which is JavaScript

Comment: @epascarello are you trolling me?

Comment: So you need to use querySelectorAll or getElementsByTagName, for loop, addEventListener, and getAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as follows.

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert(this.dataset.cid);
    }, false);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-cid="1">1</li>
  <li data-cid="2">2</li>
  <li data-cid="3">3</li>
  <li data-cid="4">4</li>
  <li data-cid="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This solved everything. Thank you my indian friend. Approved for best answer.

Comment: You don't need that IIFE. It is only useful when `i` is referred inside the function. here - https://jsfiddle.net/20u46bgh/ - code works without it as well.

Comment: @Gaurang Tandon, `querySelector` returns object that is the first element on document. At the same time `querySelectorAll` returns the array of all element of selector.

Comment: @HarishKommuri That was a typo, sorry for that, but it wasn't my point. I was talking about the IIFE.

Comment: @HarishKommuri how can I get the className of the clicked element?

Comment: Just alert `this.className` or `this.classList`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more like what happens with jQuery.

it binds a single event to the window and checks to see what the event target is, if it finds a match it will fire the callback, with the context set as the clicked element.

```js
const $ = function(selector) {
  const listeners = {}
  const bindListener = function(event) {
    listeners[event] = []
    window.addEventListener(event, function (e) {
      // iterate through the subscribed events to find any matching selectors
      const matches = listeners[event].filter(x => e.target.matches(x.selector))
      if (matches) {
        matches.forEach(x => x.cb.call(e.target, e))
      }
    })
  }
  // bind a single event listener to the window for each event type
  bindListener('click')
  bindListener('mouseover')
  // return your api
  return {
    on(event, cb) {
      listeners[event].push({ selector, cb })
    },
    off(event, cb) {
      listeners = listeners[event].filter(x => x.cb !== cb)
    }
  }
}


$('li').on('click', function(e){
  console.log(this.dataset.cid)
})

$('li:first-of-type').on('mouseover', function (e) {
  console.log('mouseover first li', this.dataset.cid)
})

$('li:last-of-type').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log('clicked last li', this.dataset.cid)
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-cid="foo">foo</li>  
  <li data-cid="bar">bar</li>
  <li data-cid="baz">baz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

That should do the trick if I'm understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll("li")`, `for..of loop` to iterate `li` elements, set event listeners; element.dataset to get `data-*` attribute value

```
for (let li of document.querySelectorAll("li")) {
  li.addEventListener("click", function() {
      let justify = this.dataset.cid;
  })
}
```

Alternatively

```
var li = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("li"));

li.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var justify = this.dataset.cid;
  })
})
```

Comment: What is `lI`...? `Not defined.`

Comment: @epascarello Are you referencing .dataset at ie?

Comment: @guest271314 slice is not safe on arguments

Comment: @WayneXMayersX Not sure what you mean concerning .slice()? Can you share further details?

Comment: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments

Comment: @WayneXMayersX Where is arguments used at OP or Answer?

Comment: @epascarello Got it